# Objective-c expression explanation

Tags: objective-c

What do these lines mean?

```
   for(ContactInfo *item in fullContactsArray) {
        if(item->contactId || item->listId)
            [contactsArray addObject:item];
    }
```

Especially, I want to know what `->` means. Please, help.

Comment: http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~wolber/SoftwareDev/C/CStructs.htm

Comment: ... and that relies on the knowledge that historically Objective-C classes were structs with all the instance variables within them. They're not in the modern runtime — there's an extra level of indirection to negate the fragile base class problem and to allow properties to be added at runtime — but the syntax has carried forwards.

Answer (score 3):

When working with pointers to structure-based data types a special dereferencing syntax allows you to deference the pointer and access a specific field within the structure in a single step. To do this we use the -> operator, as demonstrated below:

```
struct box * p = ...; 
p->width = 20;
```

The -> operator demonstrated on the second line dereferences the pointer p and then accesses the width field within the structure. While following a pointer to read or alter the value it points at, it is also helpful at times to compare two pointers to check if they point to identical values.

[Pointers in Objective-C](http://www.drdobbs.com/mobile/pointers-in-objective-c/225700236)

Comment: The `->` operator works for accessing ivars in Objective-C classes as well, not just C-structs. In fact, in the question, `ContactInfo` is an Objective-C class, not a C-struct.

Comment: In that case it would have to be that very rare bird, an Objective-C class with public instance variables.

Comment: @matt Not necessarily. If this code is in the `ContactInfo` class, the ivar can be private.

Answer (score 2):

The `->` operator works the same way as in C or C++... `item->contactId` is the same as `(*item).contactId`. (The dot in this case is the member access operator, not the property access operator.)

- The `for` loop is an example of fast iteration through an Objective-C container. It simply examines every object in the array `fullContactsArray`, assigning each object in turn to the loop variable `item`.
- `item` is a pointer to an object of type `ContactInfo`, and each time through the loop it points to a different object. The `if` statement uses the `->` operator to check the value of the `contactId` and `listId` instance variables.
- If either of those variables is non-zero, the object that `item` points to is added to `contactsArray`.

It's a little unusual to see `->` in Objective-C code, especially these days, because properties and property accessors are often preferred to direct instance variable access.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: @Caleb Sorry. Recanted. I should have verified that before I made the statement. I never saw it used before with Objective-C ivar references. But you are correct. It actually does work.

Comment: @rmaddy No worries. Like I said, it's not often seen in Objective-C. One thing I *really* hate to see is code like `self->ivar`. A) You can just say `ivar`, no need for the `self->` part. And B) if you're going to go to use `self`, you might as well make it `self.ivar` and turn `ivar` into a property.